# Spring Java Config - @Bean Overriding Bean definition not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config, spring-bean

I have a bean called Customer in project A. In project B I have project A as maven dependency.

In project B's Java Config (@Configuration) I tried to get a new implementation of bean Customer called CustomerImpl.

```
@Bean
public Customer customer() {
return new CustomerImpl()
}
```

Customer is a class here.

But my context always have Customer and NOT CustomerImpl which I wanted.

When I put a @Qualifier and use that qualifier name instead of customer() in the above config then its working fine.But I don't want to specify qualifier.

Comment: Is Customer a class or an interface?

Comment: Customer is a class here.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you say Customer is a class.

Try defining the return type from the `customer()` method as an interface (e.g. ICustomer), not a class. Make both Customer and CustomerImpl implement that interface.

```
@Bean
public ICustomer customer() {
return new CustomerImpl()
}
```

Comment: you mean the CustomerImpl as Interface ??

Comment: @user2069929 No, create a new interface (e.g. ICustomer) and make the Customer and CustomerImpl classes implement that interface. Then  change the customer method to return an ICustomer instead of a Customer.

Answer (score 0):

Give the two beans different names, e.g.

```
@Bean(name=customerImpl)
public Customer customerImpl() {
  return new CustomerImpl()
}
```

and use the name to get the instance you want, e.g.

```
@Resource(name=customerImpl)
private Customer customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed. Made 2 changes. Added @Primary and gave different method name

```
@Primary
@Bean
public Customer newMethodName() {
return new CustomerImpl()
}
```